# Difference of two metric on same space.

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that if $(X,d_1), (X,d_2) $ are two metric spaces on $X$ then difference $d_1-d_2$ may not be a metric on $X$ as difference may give negative value also . Is there any condition that make $d_1-d_2$ a metric on $X$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Paul thank ... but I want proof ...

Comment: Actually, my statement was wrong.  Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

For a metric space $X$ and metric $d$, $2d$ is also a metric on $X$.  Let $d_1=2d$ and $d_2=d$.  Then $d_1-d_2=d$ which is a metric.

Comment: This can of course be generalized to $d_2 := (1+\varepsilon) d_1$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.